# CSS Grid Browser Compatibility

Tags: css

I just completed successfully transforming my site to CSS Grid. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but scrambles things a bit in Edge and IE. In Safari for Windows it is also not right, but I believe that is an old version of Safari. I don't have an Apple to try an up-to-date version. Chrome and Firefox seems to have the lions share of usage statistics, so I am probably OK, but I thought I would see if anyone 
has other opinions before I publish the site. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Answer (score 2):

you can loook at the [can I use it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) page.

For browser which not support CSS Grid u can try a Modernizr Script. Try to look in the docs [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#grid-layout-spec)